# Add a surrounding div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Bit tricky to communicate but hope this makes sense.

I have 8 div containers and need to wrap all the even numbers with an extra div using Jquery, the desired effect like so,

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    </div></div>

  <div id="content">
    </div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('div.content:even').wrap('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
```

Note: I changed id to class since you can't have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: It works for id's as well, yes but as ken pointed out, can't have multiple elements with the same id. It is not valid HTML

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but something like this maybe:

```
$('#continer:even').wrap('<div id="wrapper" />');
```

Also note that this will probably not work to good since the is only allowed one element with the same id. Change it to a class instead. And use '.' instead of '#' in the selector.

Why do you want to do this? Is it a style issue? The it probably can be solved using CSS.

..fredrik

Edit: seems that without the editor one can't post HTML code. Ken's way is the way to do it.